# Execute a query in foreach loop and update the datagrid accordingly in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, ado.net

I have a dynamic query where I get the values from a list. I execute the query in foreach loop. I need to update the gridview accordingly like appending the rows. How can this be achieved

I have tried the below:-

```
  foreach (string id in arr)
  {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select(select name from table1 where id =");
     sb.Append("" + id + ")");
     sb.AppendLine("as Component_Name,c.[name] as Scenario_Name, a.[processid] as Component from [action] a inner join [teststep] b on a.[stepid] = b.[stepid] inner join [process] c on b.[ProcessID] = c.[ProcessID] where a.CertifySequence = 0 and a.[processid] = ");
     sb.Append("" + id + "");
     SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), connection);
      try
      {
       using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command1))
       {
          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          sda.Fill(ds);
           int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
           GridView1.DataSource = ds;
           GridView1.DataBind();
           rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }

   }
```

I cannot see gridview on my webpage. where am I going wrong

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: You are overwriting the data source in each loop iteration. With that code you would only ever see the results of the last string in `arr`.

Comment: Please try this,
string Ids = string.Join(",", arr);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select(select name from table1 where id in");
     sb.Append("( " + ids + ")");
     sb.AppendLine("as Component_Name,c.[name] as Scenario_Name, a.[processid] as Component from [action] a inner join [teststep] b on a.[stepid] = b.[stepid] inner join [process] c on b.[ProcessID] = c.[ProcessID] where a.CertifySequence = 0 and a.[processid] in ");
     sb.Append("( " + ids + ")"); 
and then use this query in command object.
no need of foreach loop.

Comment: I don't see the code that opens the connection.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras a `SqlDataAdapter` will open and close a connection for you.

Comment: @Crowcoder I haven't used a DataSet or SqlDataAdapter in probably 10 years. But from what I remember and looking at existing online info, I think you have to explicitly open the connection.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras [The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be valid, but it does not need to be open.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Crowcoder Yeap your right. Not sure why anyone uses DataSet anymore.